Interchange limit and supremum of functionals over a bounded convex set
Let $(H, \langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ be a separable real Hilbert space and $B\subset H$ be (nonempty) convex and bounded, and suppose that $(\alpha_k)\subset H$ is a sequence for which the limit $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\langle\alpha_k, q\rangle$ exists for each $q\in B$.
Note that we cannot assume the sequence of functions $\langle\alpha_k, \cdot\rangle$ to converge uniformly on $B$.
From this MSE post by David Gao, we know that
$$\label{1}\tag{1}
\inf_{q\in B}\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\langle\alpha_k, q\rangle \,=\, \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\inf_{q\in B}\,\langle\alpha_k, q\rangle
$$
if $B$ is also closed and the family $(B_k)$ of subsets $B_k := \{x \in B: \langle \alpha_k, x \rangle = \inf_{q \in B} \langle \alpha_k, q \rangle \}$ satisfies the finite intersection property.
Question: Do you know of an alternative---ideally weaker---sufficient condition to guarantee \eqref{1}?
